# Contour intersection OpenCV Java

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I have 2 images of cells. I find the contours of these cells and have `List<MatOfPoint> mopList1` (contours of first image) and `List<MatOfPoint> mopList2` (for second image, respectively). Then I must to identify changes of each cell, imposing contours of the first and second images.

first image

[image]

second image

[image]

cells contour overlapping

[image]

Finally, I need to get contours if A1,..,An and B1,..,Bn shapes.

I do this as follows:

1. Draw two contours using `Imgproc.fillPoly();`
2. Find their union `Core.bitwise_or(mat1, mat2, union);`
3. Find XOR `Core.bitwise_xor(union, mat2, intersection1);` `Core.bitwise_xor(union, mat1, intersection2);`
4. Find contours of intersction1 and intersection2.

**Do you have a better solution?**

Comment: Can you please represent your desired result in another image form?

Comment: I have 2 contours P1 and P2 (see image). They overlap. A, B - shapes formed by contours P1 and P2. As result i want to have the contours of A1,..,An and B1,..,Bn shapes as `List<MatOfPoint> result`. For example: `result.get(0)` - is the contour of A1, `result.get(1)` - contour of B1 etc. Sorry, I don't know how to represent in other form.